# How to Fix Error get node this example in sql?

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

how to get inner texts Divs in   in sql this example?

exam: size : 14.1-inch Screen (11.3"x8.4")

this is my code:

```
Declare @htmlXML as xml = N' <div class="h-product" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="" ><div class="clearfix2" style="padding:0 10px"></div><div class="notification"><<div id="l_wizard_content"></div></div><hr class="black"><div class="screen_container"><div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200 t" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN141XB-L02.jpg"><img   src="/img/screens/138/LTN141XB-L02.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 " href="/img/screens/1000/LTN141XB-L02.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg"><img   src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><br clear="both"><b>Item ID: 467454 </b></div><div class="screen_specs_container  " ><div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container " ><h4 >Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div><div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight"> LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="size">14.1-inch Screen (11.3"x8.4")&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">XGA (1024x768)&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="type"><font color="red">Matte&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></font></div><div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container"  style="display:none">Not Included</div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[<a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>]</div><div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div><div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div></div><div class="screen_prices_container"  >                                    <div class="item_currency_selector"><h5>Currency selector                                        </h5><ul><li class="active "><a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a></li></ul></div><b class="main_price">$85.99</b><div class="combo_qty_price_container">$<span >78.99</span><span class="phrase">if total screens in cart 2+                                            </span></div><div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div><div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div><div class="notify_me_button_container"><form name="notify_me" action="/English/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="notify_me" value="H01-14XGAmatte1"><input type="hidden" name="section" value="notify_me"><input type="hidden" name="notificator_id" value="model==ASPIRE 1200||screens||H01-14XGAmatte1||notificator_def==def5~~14.1^^def6~~xga^^def7~~mtt^^backlight_type~~1b^^signal_connector~~1387225725^^backlight_connector~~0^^comments_for_customers~~^^ship_only_to~~0^^threeD~~^^ips~~^^touchscreen_panel~~^^mountings~~^^ac_size~~^^ac_weight~~^^ac_color~~^^shp_wght~~438^^scr_add_text~~####^^uk1~~^^uk2~~^^dsaqotw~~^^touch_screen~~^^digitizer~~^^digitizer_only~~^^glass_protector~~^^bare_screen~~^^assembly~~^^replacement_part_type~~lcd_screen||brand==Acer"><button type="submit"  value="submit" class="submitBtn_gray"><span>NOTIFY ME</span></button></form></div><br /><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags usa"></i>Seattle, WA -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags canada"></i>Vancouver, BC -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags england"></i>Gatwick, UK -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">                            <div class="right_specs_container">$85.99 USD </div><div class="right_specs_container">$116.95 CAD</div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;69.2 GBP                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;77.45 EUR                            </div></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right"><img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left"/> &amp;amp;nbsp; <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 14.1-inch Screen (11.3"x8.4") XGA (1024x768) Matte CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=467454">Share this item via e-mail</a></div></div><div style="clear:both"></div><hr class="black"><div class="screen_container"><div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg"><img   src="/img/screens/138/LTN150XG_L08.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg"><img   src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><br clear="both"><b>Item ID: 885550 </b></div><div class="screen_specs_container  " ><div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container " ><h4 >Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div><div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight"> LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="size">15-inch Screen (12"x9")&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">XGA (1024x768)&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="type"><font color="red">Matte&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></font></div><div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container"  style="display:none">Not Included</div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4F0xPuz4Jnw?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[<a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>]</div><div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div><div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div></div><div class="screen_prices_container"  >                                    <div class="item_currency_selector"><h5>Currency selector                                        </h5><ul><li class="active "><a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a></li></ul></div><b class="main_price">$109.99</b><div class="combo_qty_price_container">$<span >99.99</span><span class="phrase">if total screens in cart 2+                                            </span></div><div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div><div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div><div class="notify_me_button_container"><form name="notify_me" action="/English/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="notify_me" value="V01-15XGAmatte1"><input type="hidden" name="section" value="notify_me"><input type="hidden" name="notificator_id" value="model==ASPIRE 1200||screens||V01-15XGAmatte1||notificator_def==def5~~15^^def6~~xga^^def7~~mtt^^backlight_type~~1b^^signal_connector~~1387225725^^backlight_connector~~0^^comments_for_customers~~^^ship_only_to~~0^^threeD~~^^ips~~^^touchscreen_panel~~^^mountings~~^^ac_size~~^^ac_weight~~^^ac_color~~^^shp_wght~~552^^scr_add_text~~####^^uk1~~^^uk2~~^^dsaqotw~~^^touch_screen~~^^digitizer~~^^digitizer_only~~^^glass_protector~~^^bare_screen~~^^assembly~~^^replacement_part_type~~lcd_screen||brand==Acer"><button type="submit"  value="submit" class="submitBtn_gray"><span>NOTIFY ME</span></button></form></div><br /><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags usa"></i>Seattle, WA -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags canada"></i>Vancouver, BC -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags england"></i>Gatwick, UK -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">                            <div class="right_specs_container">$109.99 USD                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">$149.59 CAD                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;88.51 GBP                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;99.07 EUR                            </div></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right"><img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left"/> &amp;amp;nbsp; <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 15-inch Screen (12"x9") XGA (1024x768) Matte CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=885550">Share this item via e-mail</a></div></div><div style="clear:both"></div><hr class="black"><div class="screen_container"><div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg"><img   src="/img/screens/138/LTN150XG_L08.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg"><img   src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><br clear="both"><b>Item ID: 753088 </b></div><div class="screen_specs_container  " ><div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container " ><h4 >Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div><div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight"> LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1468010881&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="size">15-inch Screen (12"x9")&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/_zalTiJ1vFY?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">XGA (1024x768)&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="type"><font color="red">Glossy&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/gt_CSbMF-5o?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></font></div><div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container"  style="display:none">Not Included</div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[<a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>]</div><div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div><div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div></div><div class="screen_prices_container"  >                                    <div class="item_currency_selector"><h5>Currency selector                                        </h5><ul><li class="active "><a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a></li></ul></div><b class="main_price">$99.99</b><div class="combo_qty_price_container">$<span >89.99</span><span class="phrase">if total screens in cart 2+                                            </span></div><div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div><div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div><div class="notify_me_button_container"><form name="notify_me" action="/English/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="notify_me" value="V02-15XGAgloss1"><input type="hidden" name="section" value="notify_me"><input type="hidden" name="notificator_id" value="model==ASPIRE 1200||screens||V02-15XGAgloss1||notificator_def==def5~~15^^def6~~xga^^def7~~gls^^backlight_type~~1b^^signal_connector~~1387225725^^backlight_connector~~0^^comments_for_customers~~^^ship_only_to~~0^^threeD~~^^ips~~^^touchscreen_panel~~^^mountings~~^^ac_size~~^^ac_weight~~^^ac_color~~^^shp_wght~~552^^scr_add_text~~####^^uk1~~^^uk2~~^^dsaqotw~~^^touch_screen~~^^digitizer~~^^digitizer_only~~^^glass_protector~~^^bare_screen~~^^assembly~~^^replacement_part_type~~lcd_screen||brand==Acer"><button type="submit"  value="submit" class="submitBtn_gray"><span>NOTIFY ME</span></button></form></div><br /><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags usa"></i>Seattle, WA -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags canada"></i>Vancouver, BC -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags england"></i>Gatwick, UK -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">                            <div class="right_specs_container">$99.99 USD                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">$135.99 CAD                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;80.47 GBP                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;90.06 EUR                            </div></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right"><img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left"/> &amp;amp;nbsp; <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 15-inch Screen (12"x9") XGA (1024x768) Glossy CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=753088">Share this item via e-mail</a></div></div><div style="clear:both"></div><hr class="black"><div class="screen_container"><div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/LP150E07_A3K1.jpg"><img itemprop="image" class="u-photo"  src="/img/screens/138/LP150E07_A3K1.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/LP150E07_A3K1.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg"><img itemprop="image" class="u-photo"  src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement"></a><div class="screen_zoom_container"><a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a><br /></div><br clear="both"><b>Item ID: 308113 </b></div><div class="screen_specs_container  " ><div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container " ><h4  itemprop="model">Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div><div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight"> LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1468010881&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="size">15-inch Screen (12"x9")&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/_zalTiJ1vFY?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">SXGA (1400x1050)&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="type"><font color="red">Matte&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/gt_CSbMF-5o?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></font></div><div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container"  style="display:none">Not Included</div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4F0xPuz4Jnw?autoplay=1"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" /></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[<a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>]</div><div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800"><img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif"/></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div><div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div><div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div></div><div class="screen_prices_container"  itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer" >                                    <div class="item_currency_selector"><h5>Currency selector                                        </h5><ul><li class="active "><a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a></li><li class=" "><a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a></li></ul></div><div class="clearance_price_container_only">$79.99                                    </div><div class="clearance_word_only">CLEARANCE                                    </div><div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div><div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div><div class="notify_me_button_container"><form name="notify_me" action="/English/" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="notify_me" value="V06-15-SXGAmatte1"><input type="hidden" name="section" value="notify_me"><input type="hidden" name="notificator_id" value="model==ASPIRE 1200||screens||V06-15-SXGAmatte1||notificator_def==def5~~15^^def6~~sxga2^^def7~~mtt^^backlight_type~~1b^^signal_connector~~1387225725^^backlight_connector~~0^^comments_for_customers~~^^ship_only_to~~0^^threeD~~^^ips~~^^touchscreen_panel~~^^mountings~~^^ac_size~~^^ac_weight~~^^ac_color~~^^shp_wght~~600^^scr_add_text~~####^^uk1~~^^uk2~~^^dsaqotw~~^^touch_screen~~^^digitizer~~^^digitizer_only~~^^glass_protector~~^^bare_screen~~^^assembly~~^^replacement_part_type~~lcd_screen||brand==Acer"><button type="submit"  value="submit" class="submitBtn_gray"><span>NOTIFY ME</span></button></form></div><br /><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags usa"></i>Seattle, WA -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags canada"></i>Vancouver, BC -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><p class="country_stock"><i class="small_flags england"></i>Gatwick, UK -<span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span></p><meta itemprop="price" content="89.99"/><meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD"/><meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition"/><meta itemprop="availability" content="OutOfStock" /></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">                            <div class="right_specs_container">$79.99 USD                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">$108.79 CAD                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;64.37 GBP                            </div><div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;72.05 EUR                            </div></div><div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right"><img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left"/> &amp;amp;nbsp; <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 15-inch Screen (12"x9") SXGA (1400x1050) Matte CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=308113">Share this item via e-mail</a></div><meta itemprop="description" content="Acer ASPIRE 1200 Replacement Screen 15-inch Screen (12"x9")" /></div><div style="clear:both"></div></div>'
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT 
          t.v.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL Local],
          t.v.value('@tppabs','nvarchar(max)') as [URL Site]
  FROM  @htmlXML.nodes('div/div') as t(v)
```

Thanks for your Tipssssssssssssssssssssssss....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
i can in C# Start and end string select and send for sql to get inner text

Comment: fix error semicolon but i cannt fix error end tag does not match start tag.line to line check but i cannt, final of project. please help me

Comment: That html is not well formed XML. So you can't even set an XML type variable for it at the moment. It's so long that it would be a pain to get all the mistakes out. Could you replace it with a shorter XML example that's well formed?

Comment: i try but source code is very bad in the product pages. i can`t even set an xml?????!

Comment: This is a common problem when trying to insert HTML into an XML type column.  And this one doesn't even have javascript ;)  Look at this way, if it's not well formed XML, then it's not XML.

Comment: I noticed that some of the links in that HTML point to PHP pages. Since you're using PHP then you probably also need to find a way to first validate the HTML before trying to force SQL Server to do something with it.

Comment: One of the problems with that xml is that all the <input> tags don't have an end tag. But if you make them single tags like `<input .... />` then those would validate.

Comment: thanks for your tips , this webpage source have very wrong but i want to parsing this page by c# and spl . select my contetn by c# and send for sql and get values by sql and send for c# by dt

Comment: what way for validate Html by c#?

Comment: I'm sure stackoverflow has questions regarding that. for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86292/how-to-check-for-valid-xml-in-string-input-before-calling-loadxml) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025986/validate-xml-against-xsd-in-a-single-method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to change to the HTML before it becomes XML.
For example text like `(11.3"x8.4")` should be changed to   `(11.3&quot;x8.4&quot;)` or `(11.3 inch x8.4 inch)`

And tags that don't have an end tag should be closed.
For example `<foo bar="bla">` to `<foo bar="bla"/>`

For the example a shorter well formed xml.
(stackoverflow only allows up to 30000 characters)

```
declare @XML xml = N'
<div class="h-product" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope="">
   <div class="clearfix2" style="padding:0 10px" />
   <div class="notification">
      <div id="l_wizard_content" />
   </div>
   <hr class="black" />
   <div class="screen_container">
      <div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer">
         <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200 t" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN141XB-L02.jpg">
            <img src="/img/screens/138/LTN141XB-L02.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" />
         </a>
         <div class="screen_zoom_container">
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 " href="/img/screens/1000/LTN141XB-L02.jpg">Zoom [+]</a>
            <br />
         </div>
         <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">
            <img src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" />
         </a>
         <div class="screen_zoom_container">
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a>
            <br />
         </div>
         <br clear="both" />
         <b>Item ID: 467454</b>
      </div>
      <div class="screen_specs_container  ">
         <div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container ">
            <h4>Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight">
            LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="size">
            14.1-inch Screen (11.3"x8.4")&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">
            XGA (1024x768)&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="type">
            <font color="red">
               Matte&amp;amp;nbsp;
               <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/">
                  <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
               </a>
            </font>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" style="display:none">Not Included</div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">
            CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">
            30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>
            ]
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">
            New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="screen_prices_container">
         <div class="item_currency_selector">
            <h5>Currency selector</h5>
            <ul>
               <li class="active ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <b class="main_price">$85.99</b>
         <div class="combo_qty_price_container">
            $
            <span>78.99</span>
            <span class="phrase">if total screens in cart 2+</span>
         </div>
         <div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div>
         <div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div>
         <div class="notify_me_button_container">
            <form name="notify_me" action="/English/" method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="notify_me" value="H01-14XGAmatte1" />
               <input type="hidden" name="section" value="notify_me" />
               <input type="hidden" name="notificator_id" value="model==ASPIRE 1200||screens||H01-14XGAmatte1||notificator_def==def5~~14.1^^def6~~xga^^def7~~mtt^^backlight_type~~1b^^signal_connector~~1387225725^^backlight_connector~~0^^comments_for_customers~~^^ship_only_to~~0^^threeD~~^^ips~~^^touchscreen_panel~~^^mountings~~^^ac_size~~^^ac_weight~~^^ac_color~~^^shp_wght~~438^^scr_add_text~~####^^uk1~~^^uk2~~^^dsaqotw~~^^touch_screen~~^^digitizer~~^^digitizer_only~~^^glass_protector~~^^bare_screen~~^^assembly~~^^replacement_part_type~~lcd_screen||brand==Acer" />
               <button type="submit" value="submit" class="submitBtn_gray">
                  <span>NOTIFY ME</span>
               </button>
            </form>
         </div>
         <br />
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags usa" />
            Seattle, WA -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags canada" />
            Vancouver, BC -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags england" />
            Gatwick, UK -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">
         <div class="right_specs_container">$85.99 USD</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">$116.95 CAD</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;69.2 GBP</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;77.45 EUR</div>
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right">
         <img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left" />
         &amp;amp;nbsp;
         <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 14.1-inch Screen (11.3 inch x8.4 inch) XGA (1024&quot;x768&quot;) Matte CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=467454">Share this item via e-mail</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both" />
   <hr class="black" />
   <div class="screen_container">
      <div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer">
         <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg">
            <img src="/img/screens/138/LTN150XG_L08.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" />
         </a>
         <div class="screen_zoom_container">
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg">Zoom [+]</a>
            <br />
         </div>
         <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">
            <img src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" />
         </a>
         <div class="screen_zoom_container">
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a>
            <br />
         </div>
         <br clear="both" />
         <b>Item ID: 885550</b>
      </div>
      <div class="screen_specs_container  ">
         <div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container ">
            <h4>Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight">
            LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="size">
            15-inch Screen (12"x9")&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">
            XGA (1024x768)&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="type">
            <font color="red">
               Matte&amp;amp;nbsp;
               <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/">
                  <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
               </a>
            </font>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" style="display:none">Not Included</div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">
            CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4F0xPuz4Jnw?autoplay=1">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">
            30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>
            ]
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">
            New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="screen_prices_container">
         <div class="item_currency_selector">
            <h5>Currency selector</h5>
            <ul>
               <li class="active ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <b class="main_price">$109.99</b>
         <div class="combo_qty_price_container">
            $
            <span>99.99</span>
            <span class="phrase">if total screens in cart 2+</span>
         </div>
         <div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div>
         <div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div>
         <div class="notify_me_button_container">
            <form name="notify_me" action="/English/" method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="notify_me" value="V01-15XGAmatte1" />
               <input type="hidden" name="section" value="notify_me" />
               <input type="hidden" name="notificator_id" value="model==ASPIRE 1200||screens||V01-15XGAmatte1||notificator_def==def5~~15^^def6~~xga^^def7~~mtt^^backlight_type~~1b^^signal_connector~~1387225725^^backlight_connector~~0^^comments_for_customers~~^^ship_only_to~~0^^threeD~~^^ips~~^^touchscreen_panel~~^^mountings~~^^ac_size~~^^ac_weight~~^^ac_color~~^^shp_wght~~552^^scr_add_text~~####^^uk1~~^^uk2~~^^dsaqotw~~^^touch_screen~~^^digitizer~~^^digitizer_only~~^^glass_protector~~^^bare_screen~~^^assembly~~^^replacement_part_type~~lcd_screen||brand==Acer" />
               <button type="submit" value="submit" class="submitBtn_gray" />
               <span>NOTIFY ME</span>
            </form>
         </div>
         <br />
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags usa" />
            Seattle, WA -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags canada" />
            Vancouver, BC -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags england" />
            Gatwick, UK -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">
         <div class="right_specs_container">$109.99 USD</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">$149.59 CAD</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;88.51 GBP</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;99.07 EUR</div>
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right">
         <img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left" />
         &amp;amp;nbsp;
         <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 15-inch Screen (12x9) XGA (1024x768) Matte CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=885550">Share this item via e-mail</a>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div style="clear:both" />
   <hr class="black" />
   <div class="screen_container">
      <div class="screen_image_and_zoom_cotainer">
         <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg">
            <img src="/img/screens/138/LTN150XG_L08.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" />
         </a>
         <div class="screen_zoom_container">
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/LTN150XG_L08.jpg">Zoom [+]</a>
            <br />
         </div>
         <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">
            <img src="/img/screens/138/30pinsCCFL.jpg" width="138" border="0" alt="Acer ASPIRE 1200  screen replacement" />
         </a>
         <div class="screen_zoom_container">
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox" title="ACER ASPIRE 1200 REPLACEMENT LAPTOP LCD SCREEN FROM $78.99  Screen" href="/img/screens/1000/30pinsCCFL.jpg">Zoom [+]</a>
            <br />
         </div>
         <br clear="both" />
         <b>Item ID: 753088</b>
      </div>
      <div class="screen_specs_container  ">
         <div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container ">
            <h4>Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight">
            LCD Screen Only&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1468010881&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Size:">Size:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="size">
            15-inch Screen (12"x9")&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/_zalTiJ1vFY?autoplay=1">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Resolution:">Resolution:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">
            XGA (1024x768)&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="type">
            <font color="red">
               Glossy&amp;amp;nbsp;
               <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/gt_CSbMF-5o?autoplay=1">
                  <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
               </a>
            </font>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterLabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" style="display:none">Not Included</div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" data-filterLabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">
            CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">
            30 pin CCFL screen&amp;amp;nbsp;[
            <a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>
            ]
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Condition:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">
            New Grade A+&amp;amp;nbsp;
            <a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;amp;height=500&amp;amp;width=800">
               <img border="0" valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" />
            </a>
         </div>
         <div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div>
         <div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:&amp;amp;nbsp;</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div>
      </div>
      <div class="screen_prices_container">
         <div class="item_currency_selector">
            <h5>Currency selector</h5>
            <ul>
               <li class="active ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=USD" rel="nofollow">USD</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=CAD" rel="nofollow">CAD</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=GBP" rel="nofollow">GBP</a>
               </li>
               <li class=" ">
                  <a href="?set_currency=EUR" rel="nofollow">EUR</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <b class="main_price">$99.99</b>
         <div class="combo_qty_price_container">
            $
            <span>89.99</span>
            <span class="phrase">if total screens in cart 2+</span>
         </div>
         <div class="product_os_sign">Out of stock</div>
         <div class="click_on_button_below_to_be_notified_container">Click on button below to be notified when the item back in-stock.</div>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags usa" />
            Seattle, WA -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags canada" />
            Vancouver, BC -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
         <p class="country_stock">
            <i class="small_flags england" />
            Gatwick, UK -
            <span class="out_of_stock">Out of Stock</span>
         </p>
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container">
         <div class="right_specs_container">$99.99 USD</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">$135.99 CAD</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;pound;80.47 GBP</div>
         <div class="right_specs_container">&amp;amp;euro;90.06 EUR</div>
      </div>
      <div class="currencies_and_shipping_cost_container" style="background-color:#fff;line-height:1.6em;clear:right">
         <img src="/a_images/mail.png" alt="Share this item via e-mail" align="left" />
         &amp;amp;nbsp;
         <a rel="nofollow" class="email_item fake_link" href="/English/section/share_item/?b=Acer&amp;amp;m=ASPIRE 1200&amp;amp;desc=Acer ASPIRE 1200 Laptop LCD Screen 15-inch Screen (12x9) XGA (1024x768) Glossy CCFL 1-Bulb&amp;amp;hash=753088">Share this item via e-mail</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>';
```

To get what you want from it, one should learn about the [XPATH](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp) syntax.
Although SQL Server uses the [XQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx), which is a superset of XPATH.

This example gets content from the `<a>` tags.

```
SELECT 
x.node.value('@href','nvarchar(max)') as [URL href],
x.node.value('@title','nvarchar(max)') as [URL title]
from @XML.nodes('//a') x(node);
```

Comment: thanks for your help.but what you fix error? and what validation this example?

Comment: Just a few regex replacements in Notepad++ : `<(?=\w+)` --> `\n<`
, `([0-9.]+)\"x([0-9.]+)\"` --> `$1&quot;x$2&quot;`
, `(<input[^>]*")>` --> `$1/>`
, `(<img[^>]*")>` --> `$1/>` . And a random online XML validation tool to iron out the remaining mistakes.

Comment: Btw, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138555/how-to-convert-html-to-xhtml) could help.

Comment: i get source code page online or local and parsing this codes.

Comment: Yeah well, if one dares to mention regex and XML in one sentence on stackoverflow then one risks a torrent of downvotes ;p  (e.g. Regex Is Not A Parser!) Anyway, [Here's a link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN regarding a regex replace.

Comment: good 'regex.repalce' , please help me for ths code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40056388/how-to-do-add-separator-between-special-content-in-sql-this-example