# How to get values of odd and even nodes in sql

Tags: html, sql, sql-server

How to get values of odd and even nodes in SQL in this example?

```
declare @htmlXML xml = N'<div class="screen_specs_container  "><div class="left_specs_container">Compatibility:</div><div class="right_specs_container "><h4>Acer ASPIRE 1200</h4></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterlabel="Replacement Part Type:">Replacement Part Type</div><div class="right_specs_container spec_highlight"> LCD Screen Only<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;view_article=1468010881&amp;height=500&amp;width=800"><img valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" border="0"></img></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterlabel="Size:">Size:</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="size">14.1-inch Screen (11.3"x8.4")<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/_zalTiJ1vFY?autoplay=1"><img valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" border="0"></img></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterlabel="Resolution:">Resolution:</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="resolution">XGA (1024x768)<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/WWPSXibVLkg?autoplay=1"><img valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" border="0"></img></a></div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterlabel="Surface Type:">Surface Type:</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="type"><font color="red">Matte<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/gt_CSbMF-5o?autoplay=1"><img valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" border="0"></img></a></font></div><div class="left_specs_container" style="display:none" data-filterlabel="Touchscreen Panel:">Touchscreen Panel:</div><div class="right_specs_container" style="display:none">Not Included</div><div class="left_specs_container" data-filterlabel="Backlight type:">Backlight type:</div><div class="right_specs_container" title="backlight-type">CCFL 1-Bulb<a class="lightbox" title="" href="//www.youtube.com/embed/4F0xPuz4Jnw?autoplay=1"><img valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" border="0"></img></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Video signal connector:</div><div class="right_specs_container">30 pin CCFL screen[<a target="blank" class="thickbox laptops" title="Video Connector" href="/img/connectors/1_big/30pinsCCFL.jpg">image</a>]</div><div class="left_specs_container">Condition:</div><div class="right_specs_container">New Grade A+<a class="thickbox" title="" href="/laptopscreen_viewer.php?edit_language=English&amp;view_article=1243967715&amp;height=500&amp;width=800"><img valign="middle" alt="?" src="/images/question2.gif" border="0"></img></a></div><div class="left_specs_container">Warranty:</div><div class="right_specs_container">3 Years</div><div class="left_specs_container" style="color:#f00">Note:</div><div class="right_specs_container">Make sure new screen has same size, resolution, backlight as your old one!</div></div>'
```

SQL code:

```
SELECT  
    t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [TitleOfSpec],
    t.v.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as [valueOfSpec]
FROM
    @htmlXML.nodes('/div/div') AS p(parent)
```

Output

```
TitleOfSpec             ValueOfSpec
 (odd nodes)              (even nodes)
------------           ---------------
Compatibility:         Acer ASPIRE 1200
Replacement Part Type   LCD Screen Only
.....                       ......
```

Thanks for any tips my friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method first unfolds the divs.
And uses row_number to get a ranking, to join the even nodes with the uneven.

```sql
WITH Divs AS 
(
    SELECT 
    row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as rn,
    x.div.value('.','nvarchar(max)') as val
    from @htmlXML.nodes('/div/div') x(div) 
)
select
divs1.val as TitleOfSpec,
divs2.val as ValueOfSpec
from Divs divs1
left join Divs divs2
  on (divs1.rn+1 = divs2.rn)
where divs1.rn%2>0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your tips dear @LukStorms . can you help me this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39932915/how-to-fix-error-get-node-this-example-in-sql

Comment: whats is this?   on (divs1.rn+1 = divs2.rn)
where divs1.rn%2>0;

Comment: The sql does a self-join of the Divs CTE.  For example if RN = 3, then RN+1=4. So you join 3 to 4.  And `x%2` is the modulus 2 of x. If the modulus 2 of a number equals 0 then that number is an even number.

Comment: For the modulus? MS has it documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx).

Comment: and for rownumber?