# How to validate a XSD in C#

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a XSD and want to make sure it follows all the standards so that it creates a valid XML. How would that be done? The only sources I can find is back checking the XML to the XSD.

Comment: [Validating an XML against referenced XSD in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/a/752774/3060520)

Comment: [Validate XML against XSD in a single method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10109483/3060520)

Comment: Unfortunately I just need to check if the XSD is valid not a XML